# Negative logic for UMA Policy in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I want to manage policies for my resources in Keycloak through a UMA compliant endpoint. So I created a resource `profile` with scopes `view_users, invite_users, edit_users`.

Then I moved on to creating Policies using the Policy API.

```
## POST
{
    "name": "can_view_users",
    "logic": "NEGATIVE",
    "decisionStrategy": "AFFIRMATIVE",
    "clients": ["uma_postman"],
    "scopes": ["view_users"],
    "roles": ["uma_postman/lg_admin", "uma_postman/sales", "uma_postman/customer_admin"],
    "users": ["37ae8b1e-f1b0-4e72-b6ac-5ad1e49f89d7", "3627cb69-23ed-474d-abec-8f31b230b730"]
}
```

I can query this(`GET http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/ng_whs/authz/protection/uma-policy`) and it seems that the policy is created properly.

[image]

Now my understanding is that since the decision strategy is AFFIRMATIVE & the logic is NEGATIVE, for any of the above roles - `lg_admin, sales, customer_admin` or the user with the above ids, I should not be allowed access to the resource.

However, when I query as a user with the above role or id, I still **don't** get access denied.
[image]

Now when I change the logic to POSITIVE for the same policy, the response is still the same. Am I missing something here? Any help would be really appreciated. :)

I was following the instructions from here - [keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_authorization_uma_policy_api](https://keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/#_service_authorization_uma_policy_api)

Comment: I am sorry. I have a question not to answer.  How to get the permission ticket from Keycloak? The documentation said to ask the resource server. ```curl -X GET \
  http://${host}:${port}/my-resource-server/resource/1bfdfe78-a4e1-4c2d-b142-fc92b75b986f```. Can get the permission like a this ```HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: UMA realm="${realm}",
    as_uri="https://${host}:${port}/auth/realms/${realm}",
    ticket="016f84e8-f9b9-11e0-bd6f-0021cc6004de"``` but My case  resource server and authz server is Keycloak.